# New car should run slow for better mileage - Myth or reality?

Tags: engine, ford, car

I just bought a Ford Ecosport and it has been only hours old. The dealer told me to drive the car at as slow speed as possible for the first 3 months (not more than 80 kmph) although my car can easily top upto 160kmph. He claims that I need to do this to "settle down" the engine and thus obtaining better mileage at a later time.

Generally, this driving-slow-your-new-car a myth or it really gives mileage later when followed properly?

Comment: For reference, the [_FORD ECOSPORT Owner's Manual_](http://www.fordservicecontent.com/pubs/content/~WOD514/~MGB~LEN/pdf/EN_GB13514og1e.pdf) (p. 113) states: "Avoid driving too fast during the first 1000 miles (1500 kilometers). Vary your speed frequently and change up through the gears early. Do not labor the engine."

Comment: Actually, I don't think my comment answers your question. It only gives guidance (actually a "**WARNING**"), but it doesn't stipulate _why_ this is recommended. Given that this is a "warning", it doesn't make you think immediately of mileage. But that's just me. :) Enjoy your new car!